# How to use the http post method on ionic 2 and Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, stormpath

I am now creating the Ionic 2 app to register and authenticate to Stormpath. When I registered the user I used the http post method.
Following function is in provider there.

```js
register(username: string, email: string, password: string, givenname: string, surname: string){
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    let options= new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
  
    var url = 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/1QI0gxrvZNfYAFsamRTwbf/accounts';

    var data = JSON.stringify({
      surname: surname,
      username: username,
      givenName: givenname,
      email: email,
      password: password
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, options).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    }, err=>{
      console.log("Error!:", err.json());
    });
 }
```

And using this function code is as following.

```js
signup(form){

    console.log('Pressed Signup button.')

    let username = form.value.username,
      email = form.value.email,
      password = form.value.password,
      givenName = form.value.givenName,
      surname = form.value.surname;

    this.stormpathService.register(username, email, password, givenName, surname);

    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
```

The HTML file is :

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="signup(signupForm)">
    <ion-list style="margin-bottom: 25%;">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>GivenName</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="givenName" name="givenName" type="text" required=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>SurName</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="surname" name="surname" type="text" required=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" type="text" required=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" type="text" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" type="password" required=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <div style="margin-bottom: 8%;">
      <button ion-button type="submit" color="light" full > Sign up </button>
    </div>

  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Error screen is :
[image]

Why I don't get response from stormpath server?

Comment: the `url` doesn't support cross origin requests, you should check if stormpath has an api which support CORS

Comment: Also an addition ; Set your headers within your components' constructor. Headers can be set once during the lifecycle of your application.

Comment: it`s because the CORS, try doing a build, in the device doesnt happen the CORS exeptions, also for develpment you can use this extension in Chrome [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to transform your http request and add your headers?

```
$http.post('yoururl', {
    foo: 'bar'
    }, {
    transformRequest: {
        body: function(data, headersGetter) {
        return myTransformFn(data);
    },
    headers: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var headers = headersGetter();
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'x-www-form-urlencoded';
        return headers;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , go to chrome extensions and search for the plugin CORS and add the best plugin you like ,then enable the plugin it will work

Answer (score 0):

In the Ionic latest versions if you are using `ionic serve` commnad then  you must have to use Proxies to prevent Preflight and CORS Issues,

First add API path and URL in `ionic.config.json` file like

```
{
  "name": "APP-NAME",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/accounts",
      "proxyUrl": "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/1QI0gxrvZNfYAFsamRTwbf/accounts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, while calling your API from `http` use the `/accounts` URL instead of the `https://api.stormpath.com/v1...` like,

```
....
    var url = '/accounts'; // use the Proxy Path here instead of Stormpath API URL

    var data = JSON.stringify({
      surname: surname,
      username: username,
      givenName: givenname,
      email: email,
      password: password
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, options).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    }, err=>{
      console.log("Error!:", err.json());
    });
....
```

After making the above changes you must rerun command `ionic serve`.

Still, if you are getting issues then refer [Handling CORS Issues In Ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)